# How do I create a function in C++ that has multiple parameters but only one is required?

Tags: c++, function

I have a function takes two "optional" parameters, but the logic of the function expects that at least one be specified. If `a` is provided, then `a` is used. If `b` is provided, then `b` is used. If neither parameter is provided, then an exception is thrown because this function needs at least one of the parameters to be given to be able to run successfully. See the code snippet for an example:

```cpp
void print_it(A* a = nullptr, B* b = nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "The parameter provided was ";
    if (a != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << a->print();
    }
    else if (b != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << b->print();
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument();
    }
}
```

I'd say it's bad practice to have a function like this that crashes during runtime when its default form is called instead of using type-safety and having the compiler check for errors.

How do I change this function signature to **require** that one of the values be provided with minimal code duplication?

Comment: Should it be able to take both?

Comment: Pretty sure what you are asking for can't be done at compile time, at least not keeping this interface.  My advice, make the functions `void print_it(A& a) { std::cout << a.print; }` and `void print_it(B& b) { std::cout << b.print; }` and then you are forced at the call site to call the function correctly or otherwise get a compiler error.

Comment: Or even `template <typename T> void print_it(T& t) { std::cout << t.print(); }`

Comment: @NathanOliver I was thinking it wasn't possible while maintaining the interface, thanks for confirming that! And those are both good alternatives, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overload this like so:

```
void print_it(A a, B b)
{
//use a and b
}

void print_it(A a) {
//use a
}
void print_it(B b) {
//use b
}
```

Or, you can use `std::optional` like explained here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional.
Example:

```
void print_it(std::optional<A> a, std::optional<B> b)
{
    if (a.has_value()) {
        //use a
    }
    if (b.has_value()){
        //use b
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The first half with the function overloading is probably my best bet. The 2nd part doesn't really solve the issue because it still allows for both arguments to be "null" and throwing an exception in that case.